# Retrofit: detect if web authentication needed

Tags: retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I'm using Retrofit (with RxJava) to download a text file.

```
 @Streaming
 @GET
 Observable<ResponseBody> download(@Url String file);
```

Everything works fine except when user is using a public wifi that need web authentication. In this case download is still successful and what I receive is a file contains HTML of that authentication web page. How do I check and raise error in this case? I tried with Interceptor, NetworkInterceptor (Okhttp), disable redirect (Retrofit) but no luck because no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either checksum your file and check it when you get it, or check the Content-type:

```
@Streaming
@GET
Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> download(@Url String file);

download("http://...")
.map(response -> {
     if(!"application/my-content-type".equals(
           response.headers("Content-Type")) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Bad download");
     }
     return resource.body();
})
```